# GAE dispatch.yaml not properly routing to services

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm having some trouble getting my dispatch.yaml to work, but I also haven't found any answers that address my problem. Most seem to be issues of putting the default service first in the dispatch, but I don't list mine at all.

```yaml
dispatch:
    - url: "*/timestamps/*"
      service: timestamps

    - url: "*/reqheaders/*"
      service: reqheaders
```

I have my custom domain setting pointing to `sub.example.com` and for some reason, every route just points to the default service, so I get an error saying `Cannot GET /timestamps` or `Cannot GET /timestamps/subpath`

Comment: Is it possibly the difference between `/timestamps` and (`/timestamps/` and `/timestamps/something`)? I've not use `dispatch.yaml` in a loong time but, if you want `/timestamp`, I think you need to pattern-match on `"*/timestamps*"` (no trailing `/`)

Comment: You may have a yaml white space issue, the dashes should be in the same column as the "d" in dispatch, they shouldn't be tabbed in.